# How do I add TokenElevationType 1937 and 1938 to my Event Viewer XML Query?

Tags: xml, logging, event-viewer

I am trying to add TokenElevationType as an additional filter for 1937 and 1938 to my XML Query. My script is currently.

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security"> *[System[(EventID=4688)] and EventData[Data[@Name='NewProcessName'] and (Data='C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe')]]
    </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

How can I add TokenElevationType as a filter?